# How to search a specific word from a xml file in nant?

Tags: nant

I have an XML file which I want to search for the `Error` word from my NAnt script. If this `error` word does exist, it will echo that `error exist`.

I didn't find any suitable way so far. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Probably confusion over being inside `${ ... }`.  Hope this helps.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Find a String" default="build" basedir=".">
<target name="build" description="various forms of string">
    <echo message="hardcoded strings" />
    <property name="stringFound" value="${string::contains('a string is a tiresome thing to search', 'tire')}" />
    <echo message="  stringFound=${stringFound}" />     
    <echo message="property strings" />
    <property name="stringToSearch" value="a property string is also a tiresome thing to search" />
    <property name="findThis" value="tires" />
    <property name="stringFound" value="${string::contains(stringToSearch, findThis)}"/>
    <echo message="  stringFound=${stringFound}" />
</target>
</project>
```

This gives

```
 [echo] hardcoded strings
 [echo]   stringFound=True
 [echo] property strings
 [echo]   stringFound=True
```